# How to open https url in webview windows store app??

Tags: windows, webview, https, windows-store-apps

http url is working fine on webview but when I try https url it shows blank page without any exception.

```
webview.Navigate(new Uri("https://myserver.php")); //it dosen't work

webview.Navigate(new Uri("http://myserver.php")); //it works
```

Is there any security certificates,I have to install or is there any other way to hit this https url?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is supported by [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).
Try to add URI in the **ApplicationContentUriRules** section of the app manifest

Comment: Thanx @alexej 
I already added this url in ApplicationContentUriRules.

Comment: @AbhinavTiwari, try to check firewall rules and load another https URI

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` supports HTTPS, The code that you are using will work perfectly, But you are not seeing it because you need to install `SSL` certificate on your Server other wise you wont see anything on your `WebView` after calling it.